# Why this XPath selects zero nodes?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Report generated by xxx -->
<report AppKey="stuffs" AppId="123">
  <physician name="AAA BBB">
     ....
     <services>
       <service id="1" diagnostic="345" />
       <service id="2" diagnostic="253" />
       <service id="3" diagnostic="585" />
     ....
     </services>
  </physician>
</report>
```

and this c# code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(file);
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/report/physician/services/*");
```

My problem is that the xnList is always empty, I tried with `"/report/*"` which return 0, tried with `"/report/physician/*"` which returns the same, only `"*"` returns the entire xml file. What I want to do is to select every `<service>` and then get their attributes. I cant seem to find a way to get every service element, because my queries always return nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use `LINQtoXML`? In that case it should be as simple as:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.cnas.ro/siui/2.0";
var nodes = doc.Root.Element(ns + "physician")
                        .Element(ns + "services")
                            .Elements(ns + "service");
```

You can also use `Descendants` which will take the matching nodes regardless of their position in the tree, like this:

```
var nodes = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "service");
```

Either way, you will get an `IEnumerable<XElement>` that you can easily map.

N.B. remember to add `using System.Xml.Linq;` in your directives.

**UPDATE:**

For mapping to the attributes, it is a matter of opinions... I would go like this:

```
var services = from n in nodes
               select new
                   {
                       Id = n.Attribute("id").Value, 
                       Diagnostic = n.Attribute("diagnostic").Value
                   };
```

`services` will be an `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>` which you can then iterate on:

```
foreach (var service in services)
{
    Console.WriteLine(service.Id + " - " + service.Diagnostic);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it, I was going to suggest this solution.  I would suggest adding in that OP can just call `node.Attribute("id").Value` or `node.Attribute("diagnostic").Value` to actually pull the data (since they weren't posting in Linq -to- XML in the first place, so they may not be familiar with the syntax)

Comment: When using this I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at the var nodes = ... part. I dont know if this will help anyone, but this is the structure of the XML file http://i.imgur.com/b0dqQep.png

Comment: I would debug that line and see if the `Root` is null and then see if any of the other bits are null one by one... I guess that the issue is simply a typo in the code. With the XML file you posted in your question (not the linked image) the code works ok... Coming to think of it, it could be the same reason why the original code did not work in the first place... Are you sure that `<report>` is the ROOT element and there is nothing else around it?

Comment: This is the complete XML, with all the data removed from it http://pastebin.com/r4FA4yYb   EDIT: Yes, `<report>` is the root element, also the XML file is generated by a medical software, so there is nothing wrong with its structure.

Comment: It's because of the namespace specification. I have fixed the answer to take it into account. Sorry, I did not realise that immediately from the image you linked :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly now. One more question, if one of the elements is missing `diagnostic`, its posible to check if its missing it or not ? Some patients dont have a diagnostic code, and I would like to ignore those.

Comment: Yes! If an attribute is missing then `n.Attribute("diagnostic")` will be null.

Comment: Then why as soon as it hits one of the patients without diagnostic it crashes with 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. The diagnostic is missing completly from the element, its not just diagnostic="".

Comment: This: `n.Attribute("diagnostic")` is null, which means that doing `.Value` will get the exception. You can do this: `Diagnostic = n.Attribute("diagnostic") == null ? "" : n.Attribute("diagnostic").Value` or even better you can filter them out beforehand: `var services = from n in nodes where n.Attribute("diagnostic") != null select ....`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the asterisk;

```
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/report/physician/services/service");

foreach (XmlNode service in xnList)
    x = service.Attributes["id"].Value;
```

Comment: Same result, the xnList count is 0 and its empty. I dont think thats its important, but I am loading my file with  `using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"D:\01-12.xml"))
            { }`

Answer (score 1):

The below XPath should work for you.

```
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/report/physician/services/service");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should select all service elements, no matter where they are in the file:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("//service");
```

Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) to find more XPath expressions